# How to fetch Json in Android using retrofit 2 as shown in below code?

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2, android-debug, android-developer-api, android-api-levels

api url: "http://btownmedia.com/?json=get_category_posts&slug=flex-print&status=publish"

my json is shown below:

```
  {
"status": "ok",
"count": 1,
"pages": 1,
"category": {
    "id": 44,
    "slug": "flex-print",
    "title": "Flex Print",
    "description": "Flex Print",
    "parent": 7,
    "post_count": 1
},
"posts": [
    {
        "id": 343,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "nk-advertising",
        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/2018/10/10/nk-advertising/",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "NK Advertising",
        "title_plain": "NK Advertising",
        "content": "<p style=\"color: #7a6666; font-family: roboto-regular-webfont; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 19px; width: 370px;\"><strong>Online advertisement:</strong> <em>Online advertisement on our website</em> means our basic service. Your business card or a visiting card sized advertisement is displayed on our website for pre-mentioned time frame.</p>\n<p style=\"color: #7a6666; font-family: roboto-regular-webfont; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 19px; width: 370px;\"><strong>Personalized page:</strong> We offer you a personalized page, designed for your business with all the details of your business- linked with your advertisement that opens when clicked.</p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>Online advertisement on our website means our basic service. Your business card or a visiting card sized advertisement is displayed on our website for pre-mentioned time frame.</p>\n",
        "date": "2018-10-10 08:08:29",
        "modified": "2018-10-10 08:08:29",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 44,
                "slug": "flex-print",
                "title": "Flex Print",
                "description": "Flex Print",
                "parent": 7,
                "post_count": 1
            }
        ],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "admin",
            "name": "admin",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "admin",
            "url": "",
            "description": ""
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [
            {
                "id": 342,
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/nk/",
                "slug": "nk",
                "title": "nk",
                "description": "",
                "caption": "",
                "parent": 343,
                "mime_type": "image/png",
                "images": {
                    "full": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "thumbnail": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                        "width": 150,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "medium_large": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "large": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "rpggallery_admin_thumb": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "rpggallery_admin_large": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "rpg_gallery_admin_thumb": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                        "width": 150,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "rpg_gallery_thumb": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                        "width": 150,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "estore-featured-image": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "estore-product-grid": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-75x75.png",
                        "width": 75,
                        "height": 75
                    },
                    "estore-square": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "estore-slider": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    },
                    "estore-medium-image": {
                        "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                        "width": 230,
                        "height": 142
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "thumbnail": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
        "custom_fields": {},
        "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
        "thumbnail_images": {
            "full": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 142
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "medium_large": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "large": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "rpggallery_admin_thumb": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "rpggallery_admin_large": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "rpg_gallery_admin_thumb": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 142
            },
            "rpg_gallery_thumb": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 142
            },
            "estore-featured-image": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "estore-product-grid": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-75x75.png",
                "width": 75,
                "height": 75
            },
            "estore-square": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "estore-slider": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            },
            "estore-medium-image": {
                "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                "width": 230,
                "height": 142
            }
        }
    }
]}
```

Pojo Class:

public class Post {

```
private Integer id;
private String type;
private String slug;
private String url;
private String status;
private String title;
private String titlePlain;
private String content;
private String excerpt;
private String date;
private String modified;
private List<Object> tags = null;
private List<Object> comments = null;
private Integer commentCount;
private String commentStatus;
private String thumbnail;
private String thumbnailSize;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitlePlain() {
    return titlePlain;
}

public void setTitlePlain(String titlePlain) {
    this.titlePlain = titlePlain;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getExcerpt() {
    return excerpt;
}

public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
    this.excerpt = excerpt;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getModified() {
    return modified;
}

public void setModified(String modified) {
    this.modified = modified;
}



public List<Object> getTags() {
    return tags;
}

public void setTags(List<Object> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}



public List<Object> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(List<Object> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}



public Integer getCommentCount() {
    return commentCount;
}

public void setCommentCount(Integer commentCount) {
    this.commentCount = commentCount;
}

public String getCommentStatus() {
    return commentStatus;
}

public void setCommentStatus(String commentStatus) {
    this.commentStatus = commentStatus;
}

public String getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}



public String getThumbnailSize() {
    return thumbnailSize;
}

public void setThumbnailSize(String thumbnailSize) {
    this.thumbnailSize = thumbnailSize;
}
```

}

interfaceAPI

```
@GET("json=get_category_posts&slug=flex-print&status=publish")
Call<Post> getListPost();
```

MainActivity.java

```
void getListPosts() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url1)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitArrayAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayAPI.class);
    Log.d("service", String.valueOf(""));

    Call<Post> call = service.getListPost();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Post> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            try {

                Log.d("Title", String.valueOf(response.body()));


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

How to fetch "posts" array in json? I have tryed as shown in above program.
can any one please help me out. In the above program all, I wanted to fetch only posts array in android.

```
    "posts": [
{
    "id": 343,
    "type": "post",
    "slug": "nk-advertising",
    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/2018/10/10/nk-advertising/",
    "status": "publish",
    "title": "NK Advertising",
    "title_plain": "NK Advertising",
    "content": "<p style=\"color: #7a6666; font-family: roboto-regular-webfont; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 19px; width: 370px;\"><strong>Online advertisement:</strong> <em>Online advertisement on our website</em> means our basic service. Your business card or a visiting card sized advertisement is displayed on our website for pre-mentioned time frame.</p>\n<p style=\"color: #7a6666; font-family: roboto-regular-webfont; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 19px; width: 370px;\"><strong>Personalized page:</strong> We offer you a personalized page, designed for your business with all the details of your business- linked with your advertisement that opens when clicked.</p>\n",
    "excerpt": "<p>Online advertisement on our website means our basic service. Your business card or a visiting card sized advertisement is displayed on our website for pre-mentioned time frame.</p>\n",
    "date": "2018-10-10 08:08:29",
    "modified": "2018-10-10 08:08:29",
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 44,
            "slug": "flex-print",
            "title": "Flex Print",
            "description": "Flex Print",
            "parent": 7,
            "post_count": 1
        }
    ],
    "tags": [],
    "author": {
        "id": 1,
        "slug": "admin",
        "name": "admin",
        "first_name": "",
        "last_name": "",
        "nickname": "admin",
        "url": "",
        "description": ""
    },
    "comments": [],
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": 342,
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/nk/",
            "slug": "nk",
            "title": "nk",
            "description": "",
            "caption": "",
            "parent": 343,
            "mime_type": "image/png",
            "images": {
                "full": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "medium_large": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "large": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "rpggallery_admin_thumb": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "rpggallery_admin_large": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "rpg_gallery_admin_thumb": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "rpg_gallery_thumb": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "estore-featured-image": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "estore-product-grid": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-75x75.png",
                    "width": 75,
                    "height": 75
                },
                "estore-square": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "estore-slider": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                },
                "estore-medium-image": {
                    "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
                    "width": 230,
                    "height": 142
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "comment_count": 0,
    "comment_status": "open",
    "thumbnail": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
    "custom_fields": {},
    "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
    "thumbnail_images": {
        "full": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 142
        },
        "medium": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "medium_large": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "large": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "rpggallery_admin_thumb": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "rpggallery_admin_large": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "rpg_gallery_admin_thumb": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 142
        },
        "rpg_gallery_thumb": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-150x142.png",
            "width": 150,
            "height": 142
        },
        "estore-featured-image": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "estore-product-grid": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk-75x75.png",
            "width": 75,
            "height": 75
        },
        "estore-square": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "estore-slider": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        },
        "estore-medium-image": {
            "url": "https://btownmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/nk.png",
            "width": 230,
            "height": 142
        }
    }
}
```

]

Comment: your JSON seems malformed, which will make it hard for ant parser to do it's job, fix the JSON first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to create an upper class for the whole object that your api returns and then get your posts from it?

Something like:

```
class APIResponse {
    public List<Post> posts;

    // add the other fields from your response if you need them
}
```

then you just have to replace your call by

```
@GET("json=get_category_posts&slug=flex-print&status=publish")
Call<APIResponse> getListPost();
```

you will then be able to simply access the list of posts easily like `response.posts`

However, if you don't want to have an upper class but directly the list of posts, you might need to use a custom deserializer. Something like this:

```
public static class PostAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<List<Post>> {
    public List<Post> deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext ctx) {
        JsonObject json = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        List<Post> vals = new ArrayList<>();
        if (json.has("posts") && .json.get("posts").isJsonArray()) {
            for (JsonElement e : json.get("posts").getAsJsonArray()) {
                vals.add((Post) ctx.deserialize(e, Post.class));
            }
        } 
        return vals;
    }
}
```

that you can register to your gson builder when creating the retrofit service:

```
Type postListType = new TypeToken<List<Post>>() {}.getType();

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(postListType, new PostAdapter())
        .create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url1)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

by doing this, every time you'll declare in your interfaceAPI a Call> it will use this adapter to get the correct results. So now you can do

```
@GET("json=get_category_posts&slug=flex-print&status=publish")
Call<List<Post>> getListPost();
```

Answer (score 0):

Post.java

```
public class Post {
private Integer id;
private String type;
private String slug;
private String url;
private String status;
private String title;
private String titlePlain;
private  String content;
private  String excerpt;
private String thumbnail;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getTitlePlain() {
    return titlePlain;
}

public void setTitlePlain(String titlePlain) {
    this.titlePlain = titlePlain;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getExcerpt() {
    return excerpt;
}

public void setExcerpt(String excerpt) {
    this.excerpt = excerpt;
}

public String getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
}

public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
}
```

}

PostArtical.java

```
public class PostArtical {
private String status;
private Integer count;
private Integer pages;
private Category category;
private List<Post> posts = null;


public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(Integer count) {
    this.count = count;
}

public Integer getPages() {
    return pages;
}

public void setPages(Integer pages) {
    this.pages = pages;
}

public Category getCategory() {
    return category;
}

public void setCategory(Category category) {
    this.category = category;
}

public List<Post> getPosts() {
    return posts;
}

public void setPosts(List<Post> posts) {
    this.posts = posts;
}
```

}

Category.java

```
public class Category {

private Integer id;
private String slug;
private String title;
private String description;
private Integer parent;
private Integer postCount;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public Integer getParent() {
    return parent;
}

public void setParent(Integer parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
}

public Integer getPostCount() {
    return postCount;
}

public void setPostCount(Integer postCount) {
    this.postCount = postCount;
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

//inside the onCreate method

```
  onCreate method{
```

getRetrofitPostObject();

}

//out side the onCreate Method

```
 void getRetrofitPostObject() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(urlp)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RetrofitObjectAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitObjectAPI.class);

    Call<PostArtical> call = service.getPostDetails();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<PostArtical>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<PostArtical> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            try {
                    Log.d("Category", response.body().getCategory().getTitle());

                Log.d("PostText", response.body().getPosts().get(0).getTitle());

                List<Post> PostData = response.body().getPosts();



                for (int i = 0; i < PostData.size(); i++) {

                    if (i == 0) {
                        text_id_1.setText("id  :  " + PostData.get(i).getId());
                        Log.d("Atrical[0]", String.valueOf(PostData.get(i).getId()));
                        Log.d("Atrical[title]", String.valueOf(PostData.get(i).getTitle()));
                        Log.d("Atrical[content]", String.valueOf(PostData.get(i).getContent()).replaceAll("(<[^>]+>)|(&[^;]+;)",""));

                        Log.d("Atrical[Excerpt]", String.valueOf(PostData.get(i).getExcerpt()).replaceAll("(<[^>]+>)|(&[^;]+;)",""));
                        Log.d("Atrical[image]", String.valueOf(PostData.get(i).getThumbnail()));
                        img = PostData.get(i).getThumbnail();

                       DownloadImageWithURLTask downloadTask = new DownloadImageWithURLTask(imageview);
                        downloadTask.execute(img);



                        // text_name_1.setText("title  :  " + StudentData.get(i).getTitle());

                    }
                }


              //  text_id_1.setText("PostStatus  :  " + response.body().getStatus());
                text_name_1.setText("PostCount  :  " + response.body().getCount());
                text_marks_1.setText("PostPage  : " + response.body().getPages());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.d("onFailure", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```